# Get Value in HTML Table using Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple table that is populated using an array:

```
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
   var object = results[i];
   (function($) {
    $('#results-table').append('<tbody><tr><td>' + object.get('Name') + '</td><td>' + object.get('Description') + '</td><td><button class="button" onclick="goToClass()">View Class</></tr></tbody>');
    })(jQuery);
```

Ideally I would like the goToClass() function to give me the object.ID for that individual row that was selected.

So for example, if I select the button on the first row in the table it would give me the object.ID for that class.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="results-table">
        </table>
    </body>
    <script>
        results = [
            {Name:1,Description:"one",ID:1111},
            {Name:2,Description:"two",ID:2222},
            {Name:3,Description:"Three",ID:3333}
        ]
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            var object = results[i];
            (function($) {
                $('#results-table').append('<tbody><tr><td>' + object['Name'] + '</td><td>' + object['Description'] + '</td><td><button class="button" onclick="goToClass('+object['ID'].toString()+')">View Class</></tr></tbody>');
            })(jQuery);
        }
        function goToClass(id) {
            console.log(id)
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

When I click the buttons, the console gives me the correct id in each case.

Comment: Just getting a reference error is undefined with the proper ID showing in console now. Any ideas?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: The issue is that I don't have the ID in my table. I just can access it using object.ID. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Do you mean the DOM ID? How do you plan to use it? to edit the DOM or to do something with your results array?